# Using different font for header

Tags: fonts, header-footer

My aim is to make header font differ from the main font. In this case I want the header to be Linux Libertine. This is my approach. I learnt it from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) that the font family for Linux Libertine is LinuxLibertineT-OsF.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-OsF}\selectfont Left HEADER 1234567890}}
\rhead{{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-OsF}\selectfont RIGHT Header}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This is what I got.

[image]

It looks like it's working until I noticed that the numbers are little bit odd. Number from Linux Libertine should look like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Left HEADER 1234567890}
\rhead{RIGHT Header}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make the numbers appear inline? Am I using incorrect font family for Linux Libertine? Maybe there is another (better) way to apply different font for header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tried this, putting `LinuxLibertineT-LF` (for lining numbers) instead of `LinuxLibertineT-OsF`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-LF}\selectfont Left HEADER 1234567890}}
\rhead{{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-OsF}\selectfont RIGHT Header}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```